# How to install ubuntu without touch screen support on a touchscreen laptop

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I need to install Ubuntu without touch screen support on a touch screen laptop due to a cracked display.  I have seen multiple posts with various work arounds, code bits and kludges to turn it off, once installed.   I don't want touch screen support turned on in the first place.  After one builds a watch, one should not have to disassemble it to start it working.
Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

To disable the touchscreen, follow these steps after you install Ubuntu :

1. Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf`.
2. Add `Option "Ignore" "on"` to the end of touchscreen section.
3. Reboot.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent initial touchscreen activation?  With a cracked touchscreen, it may not be possible to control the laptop in order to edit the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however after I install 17.10 it is not possible to launch any app or edit anything due to the active nature of the cracked touch screen.   So I need to modifiy some sort of installation configuration file to prevent touchscreen support from being activated during the install.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!